# Secure registration form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a registration form

```
function Users_Registration() 
{
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var usernames = $("#usernames").val();
    var emails = $("#emails").val();
    var passs = $("#passs").val();
    var rpasss = $("#rpasss").val();

    if(usernames == "")
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Enter LogIn.</div>');
        $("#usernames").focus();
    }
    else if(emails == "")
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Enter Email.</div>');
        $("#emails").focus();
    }
    else if(reg.test(emails) == false)
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Enter Valid Email.</div>');
        $("#emails").focus();
    }
    else if(passs == "")
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Enter Password.</div>');
        $("#passs").focus();
    }
    else if(rpasss == "")
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Введите пароль повторно.</div>');
        $("#rpasss").focus();
    }
    else if(rpasss != passs)
    {
        $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Password doesn't match</div>');
        $("#rpasss").focus();
    }
    else
    {
        var dataString = 'usernames=' + usernames + '&emails=' + emails + '&passs=' + passs + '&rpasss=' + rpasss + '&page=signup';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reg2.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#signup_status").html('<br clear="all"><div style="padding-left:115px;"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">Wait..</font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["page"]) && !empty($_POST["page"]))
{

    $user_name = trim(strip_tags(strtolower($_POST["usernames"])));
    $email_address = trim(strip_tags($_POST['emails']));
    $password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passs']));
    $rpassword = trim(strip_tags($_POST['rpasss']));
```

I have some validation in PHP

The from is working. But I dont want to put captcha.
There is way to make it secure?
My point is to make registration form disappear after 30 seconds. So you have to reopen it.

seTTimeOut(); It is after what time to run.

Should I use Interval???

Comment: Do you hate recaptcha?

Comment: No I don't))) But still  If  I am going to reCaptcha i want the Reg form was called hide back after 15-30 seconds.

Comment: You want to make the user complete a form within 30 seconds?! Sounds like the most frustrating form ever.

Comment: Also, define "secure". "Secure" against what?

Comment: Login - Email - Password You dont need more then 30 seconds)))

Comment: I agree with @deceze. Maybe you should create a Button "Login" that call via Ajax the html form.

Comment: But I may look away for 25 seconds because I have a life and then continue with your form and it will reset right in the middle after I have typed in my stupendously long name and I will rage quit your page in a heartbeat and find out where you live and beat you into a pulp. ;-P

Comment: I have a button theat calls  function Users_Registration()

Comment: This is an incredibly dumb thing to want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('#someid').val('');
    // repeat for other form fields
}, 30000);
```

So yes, it is possible. But I strongly agree with all of the above comments - this is probably something that is best left not done. Stef Heylen's answer is spot on.

Comment: Thank you this was the question and I dont just empty $('#someid').val('');

I want to close the form

Answer (score 9):

How does a captcha and the disappearance of the form provide the same security?
Captcha is to prevent automated scripts from filling in the form.
The scripts don't take 30 seconds to fill in the form and send the request, thus not providing the same functionality as the captcha.

Should post this in comment but too low rep.

Comment: Everyone help him to gain the reputation!

Comment: Here's some reputation from me.